# Can I reduce the brightness of an android phone's flash light.?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing an android camera app but due to the high brightness of the flash Everything is seems to be white.What to do.? 1 feet away is my object I have to capture the object with camera's flash light as torch mode. How can I reduce the flash intensity ?

Answer (score 6):

not possible. The android OS is limited to something like LIGHT_ON / LIGHT_OFF . You may not like this method, but if you get a tiny piece of tissue paper and put over the flash light under the back cover such that it won't move out of position, it can reduce the intensity. Not sure if you find this feasible. 
An answer based on intellect.

Comment: i want to control flashlight intensity for a bar-code scanner app, putting tissue paper doesn't sound convenient. there should be an option

Comment: I love the paper answer. Thinking outside the box! +1 for that